# Размытие как эффект замороженного стекла уходит из под элемента

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, blur

Вроде бы, код простой, как 2 копейки, и даже работает на 99% как надо. Но в моём браузере блюр "едет" как на скриншоте.

[image: Эффект поехавший blur]

Может быть, корявый браузер. У всех блюр на всю площадь блока, а у меня поехавший.

Весь день перебираю баги Chrome/Chromium. Аналогичного моему не нашел до сих пор.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  const [centerX, centerY] = [
    document.body.clientWidth / 2,
    document.body.clientHeight / 2
  ];

  const [angleX, angleY] = [
    15 * (e.clientX - centerX) / centerX,
    30 * (e.clientY - centerY) / centerY
  ];

  document.querySelector('.glass').style.transform =
    `rotate3d(-1,0,0,${angleY}deg) rotate3d(0,1,0,${angleX}deg)`;
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://unsplash.com/photos/IDb-PwCZ58o/download?force=true&w=2400") no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-clip: content-box;
  perspective: 50vh;
  perspective-origin: center center;
}

.glass {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 80vh;
  left: 20vw;
  top: 10vh;
  background: #fff4;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10vmin;
  letter-spacing: 0.75em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="glass">
  <span>GLASS</span>
</div>
```

Сравните:

[image: Эффект поехавший blur 2]

Comment: У меня норм всё (последний Хром)

Comment: У меня тоже Google Chrome Версия 87.0.4280.88 (Официальная сборка), (x86_64)

Comment: Похоже, проблема в видеокарте :-(

Comment: У меня 32-bit Win7-32bit

Comment: видюхе моей тоже лет 10 уже, ещё и на компе запущены несколько "тяжеловесов" и только чуть подтормаживает анимация, но артефакта, как на скриншоте нет.

Comment: частично лечится запредельным значением перспективы

Comment: но, всё равно, это ненормально - ведь, не на всех же компах такое.

Comment: На моём телефоне проблема есть, похоже

Comment: Вроде firefox не поддерживает blur разве нет?

Comment: У меня в лисе блура нет. Когда-то тоже были глюки из-за видюхи, в лисе, писал баг-репорт но ни у кого не повторилось. Градиенты начинались не с нуля как-будто. Потом то ли видюху сменил, то ли забил.

Comment: В мобильном хроме проблема есть на андроиде. На десктопе проблема проявляется полным исчезанием блура когда скролл происходит (когда курсор вылетает далеко).

Comment: @PavelGrishaev в firefox включается опциями `layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled` и `gfx.webrender.all` в значение `true` в `about:config`.

Comment: Все у меня нормально.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=backdrop-filter%3A%20blur   FF данный фильтр поддерживать не умеет

Comment: у меня тоже все ок!

Comment: Подтверждаю корректное отображение - Yandex browser 21.6.2.0